# Gradle CopySpec: list contents

Tags: java, gradle

In order to avoid duplication, I want to use several CopySpecs both for creating an EAR file and for creating the "Classpath:" entry in the manifest of one of the WARs. I wanted to simply read the contents of the CopySpecs for that, but I could not find any obvious way to do that, even after reading the code. Is this even possible from a build script? Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a CopySpec, I used a fileTree:

```
def myFiles = fileTree('/files').matching {
    include 'my*.jar'
}
```

So far, this seems to work fine for both purposes:

```
// ear
into('/') {
    from myFiles
}
// classpath
files(configurations.deploy, configurations.earlib, myFiles)
```